# Turning home made chicken stock into broth

Tags: broth, chicken-stock

I made chicken stock and froze it in an ice cube tray. I now want to use it to make chicken broth for a recipe. The recipe calls for 2 cans of broth (around 4 cups of broth total) so how many 'cubes' of stock should I use?

Comment: Can you melt some of them and measure the volume? Ice cube trays are far less standardized than you might think.

Comment: They are each 30mls or 1/8 cup.

Comment: So with a little math, doesn't that give you your answer? Broth is essentially seasoned stock.

Comment: Are you planning to do a lot of extra cooking (=evaporation) or mainly seasoning and perhaps adding a few vegetables?

Comment: Related: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/2995/stock-vs-broth-whats-the-difference-in-usage

Comment: JasonTrue- if I could figure it out, I wouldn't be asking the question. I'm kind of new to this, so bear with me.

Comment: Stephie, I am going to make white chicken chili. It calls for 2 cans of chicken broth. I have home made chicken stock and I want to know if I can reconstitute this to broth. JasonTrue states that "broth is seasoned stock" but broth is a lot more watery than this stock I have made that is pretty rich.

Comment: Well, if your stock ist too rich, you could always use less and "water it down" to the desired strengt?

Comment: Unfortunately the broth vs. stock distinction is driven by culinary folklore, which means definitions are far from universal. I was going more or less by this one: http://www.thekitchn.com/whats-the-difference-between-stock-and-broth-word-of-mouth-71199

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If you are just going to season your stock (according to the formula "broth = seasoned stock"), simple math will suffice: 
   4 cups = 32 * 1/8 cups -> 32 of your cubes.
- But if you are planning on using the stock and re-boil it wit fresh meat and vegs you should consider using more stock, because you will have to calculate for evaporation. Depending on your habits (do you cover your pot, how long are you boiling it) I'm guesstimating between 10% and 20% extra. If you end up with too little, you should be fine with a dash or two of water without compromising the results.

Comment: Thanks Stephie. I didn't think broth and stock yielded the same volume but, OK. Sounds good. Thats the last time I make my own though. 8hrs spent watching it on the stove, plus veg cost etc to make the equivalent of less than 2 cans of broth I can by in the grocery store for 39c a can!! LOL

Comment: I'm always making my own - Who said it needs watching? Put it on, adjust the stove to a slow simmer and forget about it... And you can make stock from leftover bones and vegetable scraps and peels, no extra cost involved. I collect whatever is suitable in a ziplock bag in the freezer and pull it out when I have collected enough. Or buy a whole chicken, cut off legs and breasts and perhaps the wings for the "real" dish & use the leftover bones. What I like best is that I get full control over what goes in my stock.