# Was my bone marrow broth boiled too long?

Tags: beef, broth

I've been making beef broth regularly but last night I forgot to turn my crock pot to low and the bones boiled all night. Does anyone know if this is ok or should I toss the broth And start over? I've read somewhere that after your stock reaches a boil it then should be simmered not boiled!!!

Answer (score 9):

Ideally it is simmered, but the proof is in the taste really as there's no safety issue. If it tastes good then use it, if it doesn't chuck it.

Comment: Yeah, if boiling stock completely ruined its flavour then tonkotsu ramen wouldn't taste so delicious! Taste your broth and see.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I will simmer it another day add my veggies simmer some more!!! Now I'm looking forward to how it will turn out!! We may on to something here.. My main concern was that I boiled the nutritious minerals out!!!

Comment: There are some other minor concerns when boiling a stock vs simmering -- they're summarized nicely in the answer to [this question](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/8416/why-should-a-stock-be-simmered-and-not-boiled)